# MySQL Error Code 1111: Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I get error code 1111 when I try and print the celebrities who do not follow anyone.

```
user (email, password, name, date_of_birth, address, type)
primary key(email)

celebrity (email, website, kind)
primary key(email)

follow (follower,followee)
primary key(follower,followee)
foreign key(follower) references user(email)
foreign key(followee) references user(email))

SELECT DISTINCT(u.name)
FROM follow as f, user as u, celebrity as c
WHERE u.email = c.email and (0 > COUNT(f.followee))
ORDER by name DESC
```

Comment: Use a proper `JOIN`.  Your query is doing the cartesian product of at least 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use column without aggregation function not mentioned in group

if you want check for an aggregated  function result you must  use having and not where

so you should use

```
  SELECT u.name
  FROM follow as f, user as u, celebrity as c
  WHERE u.email = c.email
  GROUP BY  u.names
  having  0 > COUNT(f.followee)

  ORDER by name DESC
```

*(but  0 > COUNT(f.followee)  is no sense  could be you need  another condition for check count ,  and also your join clause seems not complete)*